# Horizontal Scroll Jquery Hide/Show Scroll Arrows

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to a build a horizontal scrolling site, with forward and back arrows (you can view a rough js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/KcDqu/5/ )

This is the jquery I've got thus far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.right-arrow').click(function() {
   $('section').animate({
   marginLeft: "+=920"
   }, "medium");
   });
   $('a.left-arrow').click(function() {
   $('section').animate({
   marginLeft: "-=920"
   }, "medium");
   });
});
```

This works fine thus far. However, there are two things I want to add to this. First, on the initial display, there should be no Left arrow, because there is no content to be viewed to the left, and I don't want users just scrolling into white space.

Second, I want the right arrow to be hidden, when there is no more content to be displayed to the right for the same reason.

Can't seem to figure out the best way to do this...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But there is no content to be viewed on the right either, because the text wraps. You're forcing that by adding the margin. Is this intended?

Comment: I don't know why the text is wrapping, that is not intended. The content on the actual site will be images and text (kind of like a timeline), so the width of the section will be at least 3000px. What I'm trying to do is similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/9hubz/  But this also has the problem of the accessible whitespace on the right and left.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I want exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Code was a little difficult as your horizontal slides are hard coded to 920 and that is not always the width of the window.  This would cause some content to be skipped depending on the size of the window.

Got the arrows to work correctly with this jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var leftMargin = 0;
    var width = $(document).width();
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    $('.left-arrow').click(function () {
        $('section').animate({
            marginLeft: "+=" + windowWidth 
        }, "medium");

        $('.right-arrow').show();
        leftMargin = (leftMargin - windowWidth)
        if (leftMargin == 0) {
            $('.left-arrow').hide();
        }
    });
    $('.right-arrow').click(function () {
        $('section').animate({
            marginLeft: "-=" + windowWidth
        }, "medium");

        $('.left-arrow').show();
        leftMargin = (leftMargin + windowWidth);
        if (leftMargin > width - windowWidth) {
            $('.right-arrow').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This also will set your arrows to slide to the width of the window, so no content would be missed.

Also the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gNRkH/3/)

**EDIT:** Removed the else as they were unneeded.

Comment: Thats an interesting approuch, but you cheated with `<section style="white-space: nowrap">` (:

Comment: I don't understand how that is cheating when dwyane-wade said he didn't intend on the text wrapping in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Interesting approach. I was using right property instead of margin :) It was not making it responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can take section's `margin-left` value and use this for writing conditions. Don't forgot to use conditions inside animate function's callback function for getting accurate value.

[**Here is jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/xxge8/19/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var maxRange = windowWidth * -2;

    //note: all of the conditions are same
    var val = parseInt($('section').css('margin-left'));
    if( val >= 0 ) { $('.right-arrow').hide();$('.left-arrow').show(); }
    else if( val < 0 && val > maxRange) { $('.right-arrow, .left-arrow').show(); }
    else if( val <= maxRange) { $('.left-arrow').hide();$('.right-arrow').show();  }


    $('a.right-arrow').click(function() {
        $('section').animate({ marginLeft: "+=" +windowWidth+ "px" },600,function() {
            var val = parseInt($('section').css('margin-left'));
            if( val >= 0 ) { $('.right-arrow').hide();$('.left-arrow').show(); }
            else if( val < 0 && val > maxRange) { $('.right-arrow, .left-arrow').show(); }
            else if( val <= maxRange) { $('.left-arrow').hide();$('.right-arrow').show();  }
        });
    });
    $('a.left-arrow').click(function() {
        $('section').animate({ marginLeft: "-=" +windowWidth+ "px" },600,function() {
            var val = parseInt($('section').css('margin-left'));
            if( val >= 0 ) { $('.right-arrow').hide();$('.left-arrow').show(); }
            else if( val < 0 && val > maxRange) { $('.right-arrow, .left-arrow').show(); }
            else if( val <= maxRange) { $('.left-arrow').hide();$('.right-arrow').show();  }
        });
    });
});
```

And note that don't use `else` in these sitiations, it may create conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would have given you some links to existing slider scripts, but I'm not aware of any that handles resizing nicely.

So I've adapted some code from my own PHP exception handler :)

```
$('#list').each(function(){

  var list = $(this),
      currentPos = 0,
      itemCount = list.children().length;

  $('.right, .left').click(function(){

    // +100 = right, -100 = left
    var direction = $(this).hasClass('right') ? 100 : -100,
        nextIndex = direction > 0 ? currentPos + 1 : currentPos - 1;

    // do nothing if there is animation happening,
    // or if index is out of boundaries
    if($('> li', list).is(':animated') 
       || (direction > 0 && nextIndex > itemCount - 1)
       || (direction < 0 && nextIndex < 0)
     ) return;

    var next = $('> li:eq(' + nextIndex + ')', list),
        current = $('> li:eq(' + currentPos + ')', list);

    currentPos = nextIndex;

    // determine if the link needs to be hidden
    $('.left, .right').removeClass('hide');      
    if(currentPos === 0 || currentPos === itemCount - 1)
        $(this).addClass('hide');

    // adjust height of the container
    list.css('height', Math.max(current.outerHeight(true), next.outerHeight(true)) + 'px');

    // make the current slide absolute
    current.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: current.outerHeight(true) + 'px'
    });

    // show the next slide
    next.css({
      position: 'absolute',
      left: direction + '%',
      top: 0,
      width: '100%',
      height: next.outerHeight(true) + 'px'
    }).show().animate({left: '0%'}, 300, 'swing', function(){
      next.css({
        position: 'relative',
        left: 'auto',
        top: 'auto'
      });

    });

    // hide the current slide
    current.animate({left: (-direction) + '%'}, 300, 'swing', function(){
      current.hide();                      
    });                                       

  });

  // mouse wheel action within the list area
  list.mousewheel(function(event, delta){               
    (delta > 0) ? $('.right').click() :$('.left').click();                                 
  });

});
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
  display:none;
}    

#list{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#list > li{
  display: none;
}

#list > li:first-child{
  display: block;
}
```

HTML structure should look like this:

```
<a class="left"> left </a>
<a class="right"> right </a>

<ul id="list">                    
   <li> ... </li>
   ...         
</ul>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/NGfCP/)

The [mousewheel](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel) jQuery plugin. If you don't need mousewheel support, remove the last event.