# How to hide 'scroll arrows' toggler in an horizontal scrolling elements when reached boundary

Tags: javascript, jquery, navbar, horizontal-scrolling

I have a quite common issue but maybe in a little different behaviour from other cases.

In this case, a list of links in an horizontal bar, that COULD scroll if width of container is smaller than total space needed, for example when child elements are too much for the space available.

This bar should scroll clicking on two side arrows.

It runs but I'd like that "Arrow toggler" could be visible only if needed, so for example, completely hidden if elements are few (so, they don't fill the entire widh con container) or when left or right scroll boundary is reached...

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510395/horizontal-scroll-jquery-hide-show-scroll-arrows#answer-14511637), but is based on Window Width and anyway don't cover all cases

```js
$('#scroll-left').on('click', function() {
  var leftPos = $('.list-container ul').scrollLeft();
  $('.list-container ul').animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos - 200
  }, 800);
});

$('#scroll-right').on('click', function() {
  var leftPos = $('.list-container ul').scrollLeft();
  $('.list-container ul').animate({
    scrollLeft: leftPos + 200
  }, 800);
});
```

```css
.list-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.list-container .previous,
.list-container .next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-inline: 4px;
}

.list-container .previous {
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 40%, transparent);
}

.list-container .next {
  right: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, white 40%, transparent);
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 40px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
ul li a {
  background: lightgray;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  color: blue;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
ul li:hover a {
  background: white;
  border: solid 1px blue;
  color: $axa-blue;
}
ul li.active a {
  background: white;
  border: solid 2px blue;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-container">
  <a href="#!" id="scroll-left" class="previous">
    &lt;
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="typo14" id="allFilters">
      <a href="#">All</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="typo14 ">
      <a href="">Item 6</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#!" id="scroll-right" class="next">
    &gt;
  </a>
</div>
```